# запись в ассоциативный массив

Tags: javascript

Как можно записать значения в ассоциативный массив в сокращенном виде?

```
var mass = new Array(),
    mass['code1'] = code1,
    mass['code2'] = code2,
    mass['code3'] = code3,
    mass['code4'] = code4;
```

где значения `code1 code2 code3 code4`, объявлены выше.
Пробовал через `mass["key":value,"key":value,..];`
но выдает ошибку синтаксиса

Comment: в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, поэтому в текущей формулировке вопроса: никак. Меняйте `new Array` на `{}` и все заработает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в яваскрипте нет ассоциативных массивов, поэтому в текущей формулировке вопроса: никак.

Меняйте `new Array` на `{}` и все заработает

```js
var mass = {};

mass['code1'] = 'code1';
mass['code2'] = 'code2';
mass['code3'] = 'code3';
mass['code4'] = 'code4';

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mass, null, 2) + '</pre>')
```

Вообще говоря, ошибка даже не в том, что не правильно используется массив, а в попытке инициализации свойства, как объявление переменной.

Если разбить момент объявления и инициализации - то "заработает" и с массивом.

```
var mass = [];
mass['code1'] = code1,
mass['code2'] = code2,
mass['code3'] = code3,
mass['code4'] = code4;
```

Возможно, так же, что нужно было просто

```
var mass = [code1, code2, code3, code4];
```

Comment: Надо было упомянуть, что такое объект раз уж сказали, что не существует асс.массивов.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а что такое объект? :-)

Comment: В данном контексте полагаю аналог асс.массива. Ну а тут много [умных слов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) пишут, вплоть до "В JavaScript почти все является объектом."

Comment: @Jean-Claude, не, это как раз не аналог ассоциативного массива, потому что - это **не** массив :)